# I need a method i can call to kill a phonegap/sencha app in ios and android

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

as above i need something to end an app, do phone facilitate this ? I have scoured their documentation and cannot find a thing.

Answer (score 2):

I think for the android you can use:

```
navigator.device.exitApp()
```

Not sure cause phonegap keeps changing from version to version.

For IOS is not implemented as the usability guidelines do not allow it, therefore youre application would be rejected anyway

Answer (score 1):

For Android `device.exitApp()` and for iOS you need to set `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to true in the settings plist